# How to detect the current language of a Joomla! website?

Tags: php, joomla

I just want to generate a code that will detect the current language of my websit  in joomla  + php

Comment: which language are you talking about? Programming or spoken or browser language?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

See [getLanguage in JFactory](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getLanguage):

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

Once you have the language, you can also retrieve the locale/language code (e.g. `en-US`). Joomla! languages can have multiple locales, so you'll get an array.

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
foreach($lang->getLocale()  as  $locale) {
    echo 'This language supports the locale: ' . $locale;
}
```

If  for some reason, you are only interested in the first locale, you can simply grab the first element. You will probably need an  array, like this:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$locales = $lang->getLocale();
echo 'This language\'s first locale is: ' . $locales[0];
```

If you just want to get the selected language tag (e.g. pt-PT) you can use getTag()

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getTag();
```

Comment: who knows how to get current language flag? Thanx!

Comment: This should probably be updated for Joomla 4.

Answer (score 4):

In Joomla 3.4+, the answer by @MvanGeest still works. Here's a list of useful functions that exist on the language object:

- Get a handle on the current language through an object of type `JLanguage`

  ```
  $currentLanguage = JFactory::getLanguage();
  ```
- Get the current language name:

  ```
  $currentLanguageName = $currentLanguage->get('name');

  //OR

  $currentLanguageName = $currentLanguage->getName();
  ```
- Check if RTL (which is the case of the Arabic language and some other languages)

  ```
  $isRTL = $currentLanguage->get('rtl');

  //OR

  $isRTL = $currentLanguage->isRtl();
  ```
- Get the current language tag:

  ```
  $currentTag = $currentLanguage->get('tag');

  //OR

  $currentTag = $currentLanguage->getTag();
  ```
- Get a list of all the known languages:

  ```
  $arrLanguages = $currentLanguage->getKnownLanguages();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Is anyone looking for the ability to do the same in Joomla 4, this works for me.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
...
$lang = Factory::getApplication()->getLanguage();
$currentLanguage = $lang->getTag();
```

Comment: This seems to be merely a matter of updating how to access the `Factory` class.  The method names have been unchanged for some time. See also: https://joomlaforum-ru.translate.goog/index.php/topic,358583.0.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp