# Get the default language in the site frontend of joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How do I get the default language in the site frontend of Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getLanguage

For more details [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352241/how-to-detect-the-current-language-of-a-joomla-website)

Comment: i am not getting the default language,my default language is dutch but its shows en-GB

Comment: try this too. $default = $lang->getDefault();

Comment: thanks for you reply, it works and another code is `$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();  $language_tag = $lang->getTag();`

Comment: So you were really asking for the user's language not the default language for the site? You might want to change the title to reflect that just to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 9):

After hours of reading through web and sources, I found this would be the correct answer:

```
JComponentHelper::getParams('com_languages')->get('site')
```

Comment: This worked for me (default lang is not En). Thanks!

Comment: @beej: en is neither a default lang for me. perhaps that's why other ideas wouldn't work for us.

Comment: This should be the correct answer for the question asked! The accepted answer if for getting the current language(which is not the title of this post!

Answer (score 1):

To get the users language on Joomla 3 you can do

```
JFactory::getUser()->getParam('language', JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag());
```