# How to get direction of current language in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, right-to-left

I know that we can get current language in Joomla by

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

now I want to know "How to get direction of current language in joomla 2.5?"

I try to use

```
dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>"
```

but It's not work and it returns empty string.

Comment: does `echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();` is working ?

Comment: I don't use that but It's in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352241/how-to-detect-the-current-language-of-a-joomla-website

Comment: please check it and let us know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->direction` can only be used on templates and there is no `JLanguage` property to get the actual value `ltr` or `rtl`. So you could do something along the lines if this instead:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$dir = $lang->get('rtl');

if($dir == 0) {
    //do soemthing
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may inspect your current language metadata and check the rtl property

```
$meta = JFactory::getLanguage()->getMetadata(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag());
echo $meta['rtl'];
```

If $meta['rtl'] is 1 you are using a right to left language.

Pls. note that `$this->direction` is used on templates.